# Download file using chrome.downloads API

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The extension I have made has the functionality to record the screen. At the end of recording the video has to be saved in the local machine. chrome.downloads API opens a windows toolbar to save the video file in a desired location. I want to make the download location path as well as the file name to be pre-defined. How can I do that ?

Comment: Only sub-path inside the default downloads directory can be specified along with the file name as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download).

Comment: I don't want that Save As dialog that getting popped up. Instead I need to save the file automatically , can i do that ?

Comment: Yes, look for examples that create `a` DOM element, set its `download` attribute to the file name and `href` to the file data URI or a blob object URL.